# How to create a task in SSIS, in which the user can change the values of variables, every time he runs the package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have created a package in ssis in which i use some date-variables inside my SQL statements ( i.e declare @DateIn ="2018-02-22" and declare @DateTo = "2018-03-22"), in order to load the corresponding data inside the tables of the data warehouse.

What I need to do is to create a task or a different package, which will give me the possibility to define externally the values of these variables, every time i run it, in order to fill in the tables of the warehouse with the data that corresponds to the dates i set every time.

From what I've read, I should maybe use a script task or an execute sql task or parameters

Could you help me please? Or could you suggest me a good tutorial/link?
I have found plenty but can't decide if they meet the needs of what i am describing above.
Thank you

Comment: You can execute packages programmatically (with stored procedures) using the SSIS catalog in newer versions. I have worked on a project where we had a web front-end that the user selected parameters--which were then used to execute packages. This might work for you. The key is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15#ProjectsAndPackages

Comment: Use Parameters, not variables. I *assume* you're using SQL Server 2012+ and the SSISDB though (if not, why not)? *"Or could you suggest me a good tutorial/link? "* however, is off-topic for Stack overflow.

Comment: Think twice about this - SSIS is not an end user tool. What are you actually doing? Generating exports?

Comment: i just want to create a task in which the user has the option to insert from the begging of the package the wanted date , in order to populate the tables with the right data. and not to have to go in each sql query i have writtern inside the package and change the @dateto by hand.

Comment: As already mentioned the _first_ thing to do is make sure they are parameterised (create a package or projecty parameter).The only place you should see any dates is for the default values of your parameters. If all this work is being done on the same SQL Server you can just use a stored procedure to do it all

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments and help, i ll try them and update with the steps of my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create DTSX package with variables `@DateStart` and `@DateEnd`
2. Create table containing 3 columns DateStart, DateEnd, Active
3. Create stored procedure that reads `DateStart`, `DateEnd` where Active = 1 from your newly created table and does an alter on the SQL Server Job updating your variables value that are inside of your DTSX package  with your desired value using sp_update_jobstep

   [See link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/update-sql-job-step)

   Ex of command:

   ```
    dtexec /f YourPackage.dtsx
            /set \package.variables[DateStart].Value;myvalue
            /set \package.variables[DateStart].Value;myvalue
   ```

   Add `sp_start_job` inside the stored procedure to start the job with the new variable values.
4. Create job with 1 step containing the execute of the stored procedure from Step 3
5. All you need to do is update the values from your table created in Step 2 and then execute job to run the stored procedure to update DTSX job exec command and start it. You can trigger this from a website and control the tables values from textboxes.

Also specific Permissions are required and the SP that updates the SQL Agent job needs to be run by Sysadmin

Answer (score 1):

Good question by the way for the new learner!
There are many ways for this scenario,few of them I have mentioned below.
1-Create variable in variable pane @DateIn and @DateTo for storing the date and data type will be date.
Now put 2 entry in Excel ,text or xml for these two variables and call it by using **foreachloop container** and assign this to variables.
2-Create a SQl table in which you can store those values either by manually on daily basis or load the table with excel ,text ,xml or csv file and call the table in **Execute SQL Task** and select the result set and pass the result set values to the variables.
I hope it will solve your problem.